# About a terminology in fluid dynamics

Tags: terminology, fluid-dynamics

I am now reading some references about mathematical fluid dynamics, mainly about Euler equations.

There is a phrase "small scale creation" I cannot understand.

Does it mean the growth of vorticity gradient?  Any why?

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: Out of context it is hard to be certain what you mean here. A situation I have heard referred to is one where the velocity field is essentially zero outside of a small region where it is significant.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your reply. A typical article is like this one https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.4799